# Problems in select sql query for autocomplete

Tags: asp.net, web-services

i have one textbox.prefixtext should be give anything it should be disply.But,i need give some condition in where clause of query.Example:

```
"select ItemName from ListItems Where ItemName like @myParameter+'%' AND Listname=???? GROUP BY ItemName"
```

How to pass Listname Parameter in webservice?it is possible..advance thanks

Comment: please try to explain your question more clearly. 
http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: i want to display autocompleted textbox in my website.i give any prefixtext means it display corresponding value in database.But,Now i need give some condition for query....

Comment: sorry, still i can not understand your requirement clearly but see if this is what you want. http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/AutoComplete_Textbox_Addtional_Parameters.aspx